# Handle javascript iframe down case when doing postMessages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, window, postmessage

I am trying to handle **iframe** is down case on my react js application

I am doing postMessages to the iframe like this `iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(mesage, origin);`

Sometimes iframe origin can be down , with some reasons , I want to handle this part , in the console , I am get this error

```
Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('localhost') does not match the recipient window's origin ('null').
```

Question is how can I catch it ? Iframe can be load and everything can be fine , but after x minute it can be down , how to catch this error ? any ideas will be appreciated